# Copy colored output from Mac OS X terminal

Tags: macos, colors, terminal.app

I see a nicely colored output in my terminal.

The terminal has a "Export Text As" command but it saves a plain-text file without the colors. Same with copy&paste.

Do you know a way to save terminal output including colors?

Comment: If this is important to you, please let Apple know via http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html (Applications/Utilities feedback area) or https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ (requires registering for a free developer account).

Comment: Terminal now has a list of options for the basic Cmd-c copy command under `Edit -> Copy Special`, where you can toggle between Plain Text and rich text options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that if you select text in the Terminal, then copy it, then paste it into an application that supports rich text (e.g. Mail, TextEdit, Word), then the text color will be preserved.

It appears that in Mail and TextEdit, the background color of the terminal is also pasted; in Word, it is not.  I'm not sure how to explain this discrepancy.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?  This doesn't work on 10.7.4.

Comment: @Wildcard It works for me on 10.11.3.  I don't remember which version I was using when I wrote this

Comment: I had trouble using regular Copy to paste into Mail — the colors were lost — but it worked when I used Edit -> Copy Special -> Copy Without Background Color (which I preferred anyway).  It even worked with option-drag to create a rectangular selection. (10.12.6)

Comment: Pasting into TextEdit worked great for me.  Also if your email client has html formatting turned on, pasting into there should work as well.

Answer (score 60):

Amazing how posting a question boosts ones creativity.

I can open "Print" dialog and save to PDF and then copy colored output from the PDF.

Also iTerm2 terminal app has a shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>OPT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> that copies with formatting.

Comment: This solution is perfect for maintaining colored output when creating terminal examples in a Keynote presentation. Thx!

Comment: @Wojtek: You're welcome, even though it cost me a little reputation when you unaccepted my answer... ;-)

Comment: +1 for the iTerm2 shortcut! Why is that not even in the meny???

Comment: That ... is definitely the most useful find since a long time!!!

Comment: If you `⌘ + ⌥ + C` from iTerm2, open Keynote, and paste it, it will import it as table data. I haven't quite figured out how to format the data in a useful way, but there's potential there.

Answer (score 9):

you can try to paste the colored output to the clipboard like this:

```
% command_which_produces_colors | pbcopy -prefer rtf
```

which puts some rtf (possibly colored and formated) stuff into the pasteboard of macos. you can then use any other that understands richtext to access the clipboard.

this is obviously not the same as "select it with the mouse" but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: Doesn't seme to work. First problem is that  command_which_produces_colors notices it doesn't print to the console so it skips the colors. I can force some of them to print colors anyway, so following command outputs colors to the terminal:
CLICOLOR=1 CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -alh | tee
But pbcopy copies no colors:
CLICOLOR=1 CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -alh | pbcopy -prefer rtf

+1 for pbcopy/pbpaste commands. It's great for copying long files to clipboard: "pbcopy < longfile.txt"

Comment: When I try this, if `command_which_produces_colors` produces ANSI codes, then `pbcopy -Prefer rtf` just copies the text including the ANSI codes (e.g. it copies `[0;34mText` for blue `Text`).  It seems as though converting the ANSI codes to RTF may be required as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 8):

Based on @akira's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/229710/127404), I came up with the following:

1. Download the [source package](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/ansifilter-1.11.tar.gz) for [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) (can also be installed by `brew install ansifilter`)
2. Follow the instructions under INSTALL to build and install ansifilter
3. Run `<command that produces colors> | ansifilter --rtf | pbcopy -Prefer rtf`

   - You may need to pass arguments to `<command that produces colors>` to force it to produce colors even though its output is piped, e.g. `ls --color=always` instead of just `ls`
4. You can then paste into an application that supports rich text (e.g. Mail, TextEdit, Word)

Answer (score 2):

OS X has several keyboard shortcuts (hotkeys) for copying the screen. These will save your screenshots as a jpg files on the desktop. Here's a list of them:

```
Cmd-Shift-3                             Take snapshot of the whole screen
Cmd-Shift-4                             Take snapshot of the selected area
Cmd-Shift-4-Spacebar                    Take picture of a window
Escape                                  Cancel
Hold Spacebar after Drawing the region  Move the selected area
Hold Option                             Resize selected area
Hold Shift                              Resize selected area horizontally 
                                        or vertically
```

There's also a "Grab" application located in the Applications | Utilities folder that does the same job, plus has a few extra features such as delay.

**Update**

In Snow Leopard (10.6.8) the default screenshot format is png not jpg, although that can be changed to any one of many others -- including pdf -- using the free 3rd-party [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) preference settings utility.

Comment: a .jpg is kind of not as nice as "pure" text.

Comment: +1 for the lesser known shortcuts for selection area.

Comment: @akira: The OP wants colors -- something you can't do in a plain-text format unless you count embedded [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) -- and those would need something to interpret them like a terminal emulator, but then you're back to the original problem.

Comment: @martineau: depending on the capabilities of the clipboard colors are saved by markup (eg, richtext or html) when you copy from a browser or from word or from xyz. and, depending on the application that receives such marked up snippets they can show the colors AND the text quite ok. the terminal receives ascii escape sequences, correct, but just because it receives ascii escape sequences does not mean it has to a) store them (eg, think html-terminal) b) it can enhance the selected text a lot of ways (you can put different mime-types at a good clipboard at once).

Comment: @akira: IF the application allows you to select some or all off what appears in its window(s), and IF it also supports Cmd-C (copy), allowing you to copy that to the clipboard, and IF you have some other application running that understands the format of what was placed on the clipboard, then yes, after a Cmd-V (paste) you might end up with something that had the text in it in a form you could edit and/or restyle. It's not clear at all that's what the OP wanted. The OS screengrab keys listed work with *any* application (or potentially multiple ones at the same time).

Comment: take a short look at http://manpagez.com/man/1/pbpaste/osx-10.4.php and http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/37233/0/page/3 ... and yes, obviously makeing pixels is 'easier' at creation time, its just that ocr doesnt work that well if you want to extract that text back, thats all i was saying.

Comment: Yes, that's a viable alternative (less key strokes) to printing to PDFs when you:
1. need only small portion of console output
2. you don't need to be able to select and copy text from this saved output

Comment: @akira A JPG is a *really* poor choice of image format for something like a screenshot. Large areas of single color and sharp single pixel lines etc. all over it. Fortunately, Apple are not that silly and the file it saves is a PNG. http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/

Comment: @rjmunro: yeah, especially if you make screenshots from applications like photoshop or a browser showing something like http://flic.kr/p/avFtqb ... so, thank you for your wisdom on this important issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is via the excellent Textmate 2 app.

1. Copy from R graphical window
2. Paste into an empty textmate document
3. Change document type to R Console or R as preferred
4. Use the copy-with-style tmbundle (shift-cmd-c)
5. Paste into mail app compose window

I have to say it would nice if shift-cmd-c worked directly in the R console window.

Answer (score 0):

In iTerm2 you can go to `Edit` → `Copy with Control Sequences` to copy with the ANSI colour codes.

Then you just need something that will render ANSI colours.